Enable pi-hole along with hotspot
I installed Pi-hole successfully but I'm enabling hotspot, so I got this error:
FTL failed to start due to failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use (by dnsmasq)
When I kill dnsmasq, Pi-hole works fine, but I'm not now able to enable hotspot, I get:
dnsmasq[22153]: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use
I uninstalled dnsmasq-base and Pi-hole is working fine, but when I try to enable hotspot, I get this error:
NetworkManager[116210]: <warn>  [1734879323.7233] device (wlp0s20f3): ip:shared4: could not start dnsmasq: Could not find "dnsmasq" binary
Is there a way to use Pi-hole and hotspot at the same time? Can I configure hotspot to use Pi-hole instead of dnsmasq?
UPDATE:
I have Ubuntu 22.04

See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=375778 for a similar question.

@guiverc I updated the post.
